Problem in replacing .env variables to firebase.ts
Im trying to replace variables(apiKey, authDomain, etc) into firebase.ts, but it said that " Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key)." (I checked the apiKey and others varaible multiple times) This is my code:
firebase.ts
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ID,
  measurementId: import.meta.env.VITE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const firestore = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { app, auth, firestore, storage };

.env
VITE_API_KEY=MY_API_KEY
VITE_AUTH_DOMAIN=MY_AUTH_DOMAIN
VITE_PROJECT_ID=MY_PROJECT_ID
VITE_STORAGE_BUCKET=MY_STORAGE_BUCKET
VITE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=MY_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
VITE_APP_ID=MY_APP_ID
VITE_MEASUREMENT_ID=MY_MEASUREMENT_ID

Is there any steps I did wrong? Tysm
